# how to use foxpro in android

Tags: android, console, foxpro

I have a running app on fox pro which is developed using **`DOS`**. And its working very fine on the computer system. But due to the requirement of the users, now they want it to run on the android device.

**So**

**1.** Can you please tell me whether any plugin or bridge is already there in the market or should I have to develop one. I am basically looking for the bridge which can make communication between Android and fox pro. I don't know whether this is possible or not.

**2.** Any solution to open console in the android device where I can execute DOS commands in Android device like I do in the computer system.

*Specifically I don't want for redevelopment, but if there is no way to achieve then let's see.*

Comment: You need to develop *RESTFul* webservice by creating web-project. That way you can expose *Foxpro* database functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to open console where I can write the DOS commands?

Comment: Because I want to use it locally. Thats why I wanted to do so.

Comment: I have to ask: Is this a serious question?

Comment: yes I have an running app from last 10years, but now with the users requirement,they want it on the android device

Comment: I am asking the question here,if I am unable to explain it properly then please make a comment before down voting it.else others also will not pay attention here

Comment: Can downvoter tell me why this question is down voted??

Comment: The Android version of Doxbox may be a solution.  It is on the market already ("adosbox" I believe).

Comment: @nick You are asking for support on a OS which has been discontinued  since 2000. You are also not clear in describing if you want to run Fox Pro on Android and the data lives on a Android device or you want to communicate with an existing Fox Pro instance running on PC and have Android communicate with it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang : the fox pro should be on the device only.thats why asked for opening the console using android in question 2.I want to know whether it is possible to keep foxpro sofware on the android device and communucate wht that software using android console.

Comment: @eyespyus can you tell me how it is possible

Comment: @nick, it is Dos with limited to no connectivity options (as is plain Dos). It will and does run DOS ,apps and games. There is a website with information ;)

Comment: So I can assume that I have to redevelop the existing application in for pro into android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can run DOSbox under Android:

http://androiddosbox.appspot.com/

I've never tried this, but maybe it will provide what you're looking for.

Comment: its right.thanks,but i  wanted to develop the same by me itself,thts why i wanted some tutorial or overview that how its possible

Answer (score 0):

Between a combination of psgsdk and Appery.io and software that helps convert screens from SCX files into Appery, this is a lot easier now. I've done this several times and have apps in both Google play and IOS app store that are FoxPro apps. The back end and all code is Visual FoxPro and the front end is Appery. @abigdreamer on twitter gets ahold of me -- let me know if I can help -- Know this post is years old but others might need the same.